# How to show a modal dialog using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Earlier i was using a jquery dialog to show a pop-up message. However I need to use boostarp for my project and I am not able to figure out a way to actually show the pop-up.
The code that i used for my jquery dialog:

```
showUserWarningMessage: function (title, message, callback, scope, username) {
    var $dialog = $("#dialog-move-user-warning");
    $dialog.dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 580,
        modal: true,
        top: 200,
        dialogClass: "warning-dialog",
        title: title,
        position: ["center", 200],
        open: function () {
            $dialog.find(".btn-default").on("click", function () {
                $dialog.dialog("close");
            });
            $dialog.find(".btn-primary").on("click", function () {
                $dialog.dialog("close");
                if (callback) {
                    if (scope) {
                        callback.call(scope);
                    } else {
                        callback();
                    }
                }
            });
        },
```

And he code im writing for bootstrap modal:

```
showAlertMessage: function(options) {
     var $dialog = $("#dialog-move-user-warning");
     $dialog.modal("show");        
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dialog-move-user-warning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">User Info</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason its not displaying anything on the screen, though the background gets disabled as though there is an overlay popped, but can see it. i tried changing the defaults set for the `class="modal"`, but it didnt help.
What im i doing wrong, or anything additional needed for the overlay to display?
is there any `css` that i need to change?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't really tell you if there are styles you need to change without seeing them first.

Comment: **When** does your JS code that makes your modal dialog visible run?  Have you looked at [`Bootstrap` examples](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)?

Comment: you don't have any content, just the header and footer. add a <div class="modal-body"> with your content.

Comment: Check this samples http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-modals.php

Comment: @dandavis: well, this is just a mock that im trying to show when i run the '$dialog.modal('show')'. atleast can i expect to see an empty overay with title as 'USer Info' with this html template?

Comment: yes, i have tried looking at the examples and did the same way as mentioned in examples, still no luck..

Comment: i got a blank screen like that one time when bootstrap.js was getting added more than once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a modal using Bootstrap, why don't you use Bootstrap?

**1. Add the modal html to your page.**

The modal html you've provided is valid, if you are not certain, you can find the exact code and more examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

**2. Add a trigger to your page.**

Data-target should be equal to your modal ID, which is #dialog-move-user-warning in your case.

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Launch demo modal
    </button>
```

**3. Make sure you have bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css included on your website.**

The Bootstrap modal relies heavily on bootstrap.js. You don't need everything, what you will find in the JSFiddle below is just enough.

http://jsfiddle.net/fgxmcnd2/3/

Answer (score 1):

Below are multiple ways opening modal dialog using bootstrap

Method 1: Open modal window using javascript

```
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

Method 2:

```
<button (click)="deleteStudent(item.student_id)" class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>&nbsp;
```

Method 3:

```
<button class='btn btn-success' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalMore">Open</button>
```

Method 4:

```
<button href="#mypop" class="btn btn-success" data-backdrop="false" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="mypop" class="modal fade">
    //modal code here
</div>
```